# Reading and printing a random element from a binary file

Tags: java, file, binary

right now I have a binary file that is filled with 5 sets of questions, answers and point values. I need to pick a random question, and its matching answer and point value from the binary file and print it out. How would I go about doing this because with the binary files I don't think I can just use a `nextLine()` and such. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.io.*;

public class Trivia implements Serializable  {
private String question;
private String answer;
private int points;

public Trivia() {
    question = " ";
    answer = " ";
    points = 0;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setQuestion(String q) {
    question = q;
}

public void setAnswer(String a) {
    answer = a;
}

public void setPoints(int p) {
    points = p;
}

}
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Trivia[] t = new Trivia[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        t[i] = new Trivia();
    }

    t[0].setQuestion("How many states are in the US?");
    t[0].setAnswer("50");
    t[0].setPoints(1);

    t[1].setQuestion("Who is the richest person in the US");
    t[1].setAnswer("You");
    t[1].setPoints(1);

    t[2].setQuestion("How many senators come from each state?");
    t[2].setAnswer("2");
    t[2].setPoints(2);

    t[3].setQuestion("What is the largest state?");
    t[3].setAnswer("Alaska");
    t[3].setPoints(2);

    t[4].setQuestion("Who was the thrid president?");
    t[4].setAnswer("Thomas Jefferson");
    t[4].setPoints(3);

    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("trivia.dat"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not open file");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    try {
        outputStream.writeObject(t);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Writing error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;


    try {
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("trivia.dat"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Trivia[] test = null;

    try {
        test = (Trivia[]) inputStream.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Reading error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

ArrayList<Trivia> triviaQuestions = new ArrayList<Trivia>(5);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("trivia.dat"));
triviaQuestions.add((Trivia) ois.readObject()); // This should be repeated (looped) until all questions are read


}
```

Here is a screenshot of the binary file: 
http://imgur.com/a/zask2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the amount of questions is not that large, I would suggest reading the full file while storing the question objects (including theire answer property and points) in a list. You can then request a random question from this list.

```
List<Question> questions = readQuestions();
Question randomQuestion = questions.get((new Random()).nextInt(questions.size()));
```

**Update regarding the binary file**

It looks like the file was created using the ObjectOutputStream. To read it one can use the [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) class. Read every object one by one add it to the list. You can use it like this:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("path_to_file"));
tiviaQuestions.add((Trivia) in.readObject()); // This should be repeated (looped) until all questions are read
```

Your final Driver class should look like this:

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Trivia[] t = new Trivia[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        t[i] = new Trivia();
    }

    t[0].setQuestion("How many states are in the US?");
    t[0].setAnswer("50");
    t[0].setPoints(1);

    t[1].setQuestion("Who is the richest person in the US");
    t[1].setAnswer("You");
    t[1].setPoints(1);

    t[2].setQuestion("How many senators come from each state?");
    t[2].setAnswer("2");
    t[2].setPoints(2);

    t[3].setQuestion("What is the largest state?");
    t[3].setAnswer("Alaska");
    t[3].setPoints(2);

    t[4].setQuestion("Who was the thrid president?");
    t[4].setAnswer("Thomas Jefferson");
    t[4].setPoints(3);

    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("trivia.dat"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not open file");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    try {
        outputStream.writeObject(t);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Writing error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
    ArrayList<Trivia> triviaQuestions = new ArrayList<Trivia>();

    try {
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("trivia.dat"));

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ // Repeats the content of the loop five times
            triviaQuestions.add((Trivia) inputStream.readObject());
        }
        inputStream.close(); // Closes the input stream because it is not longer needed


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Trivia yourRandomTrivia = triviaQuestions.get((new Random()).nextInt(triviaQuestions.size())); // This will be your random question

}

// You did not get an auto complete suggestion because you typed outside of a method


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by list?

Comment: For example an ArrayList: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Ahh, okay. That's what I was leaning towards. How would I pull the info from the file to the array list though? Because the info in the file is just binary jibberish

Comment: @ProgrammingGuy123 I updated the answer. Did it help? If not, let me know.

Comment: It did, the problem I am getting is this. So I created my array list `ArrayList<Trivia> triviaQuestions = new ArrayList<Trivia>(5);`. I tried to use the ObjectInputStream by doing this `triviaQuestions = inputStream.` but I am not getting any read methods from this line.

Comment: Nice, I got messed up with that first line, thank you.

Comment: Good that my answer. You can accept the answer if that solved your question. If not, comment again...

Comment: Is this the file name? `"pfad_zur_datei"`

Comment: Yes. It should be "trivia.dat". I intentionally used my native language (German). It translates to: path_to_file

Comment: Okay, for some reason still I am not getting any methods from triviaQuestions. Meaning, when I do `triviaQuestions.` no methods drop down in a list. Could I have possibly setup the arraylist wrong?

Comment: I don't know. Could you please update your code given in your question so i can see what you currently have.

Comment: This is what I have. `ArrayList<Trivia> triviaQuestions = new ArrayList<Trivia>(5);
 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("trivia.dat"));
 triviaQuestions.add((Trivia) ois.readObject()); // This should be repeated (looped) until all questions are read`

Comment: I mean the full code of the class you are currently working on. I assume this would be "Driver".

Comment: You did not get a suggestion because you were working outside of a method body. I updated my answer with the final solution and commented the relevant steps.

Comment: What a rookie mistake. Thank you so much.